# Running into an odd issue with postgres jdbc driver

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, pgpool

I am using the Postgres jdbc driver  with pgpool. Running into this really odd issue which doesn't give me a lot of information on what its complaining about.
Here is the stack trace. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

```
Apr 19, 2018 3:28:39 PM org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection <init>
FINE: PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.1.4
Apr 19, 2018 3:28:39 PM org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection setDefaultFetchSize
FINE:   setDefaultFetchSize = 0
Apr 19, 2018 3:28:39 PM org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection setPrepareThreshold
FINE:   setPrepareThreshold = 0
Apr 19, 2018 3:28:39 PM org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl openConnectionImpl
FINE: Trying to establish a protocol version 3 connection to bdlgpmdev01.isus.emc.com:7500
Apr 19, 2018 3:28:39 PM org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl openConnectionImpl
FINE: Receive Buffer Size is 184,640
Apr 19, 2018 3:28:39 PM org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl openConnectionImpl
FINE: Send Buffer Size is 43,520
Apr 19, 2018 3:28:40 PM org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection isValid
WARNING: Validating connection.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid server parameter
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2477)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2190)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:300)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:169)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:136)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.isValid(PgConnection.java:1311)`
```

Comment: Please, can you add the code you're using to try to get a connection?

Comment: What is your Postgres version? The driver version? pgPool version?

Comment: Running it against Greenplum 5.4.1.